# How to change cursor?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-tree

In the [angular-ui-tree](https://github.com/angular-ui-tree/angular-ui-tree) I've noticed that items has the drag or move cursor which is good when having items that we need to be drag-gable.

But how can I set the cursor to normal arrow instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add following CSS

```
.angular-ui-tree-handle {
    cursor:default !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS to set the default cursor on the element:

```
cursor: default;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor